# Set List Adapter CheckBox and Multi Choice Alert Dialog

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I am creating a chat app so I need to implement the broadcast feature, I have placed an AlertDialog within a button of another AlertDialog - so that when the user wants to add contact(s) or select all the contact names from the simple cursor adapter they are returned.

My problem is that when the contacts button is clicked the ListView shows the contact names correctly but when I click both the "Done" or "Select All" buttons, they produce a NullPointerException error instead of the checked names. Please help - thanks in advance.

Code is below for the callBroadcast() function

```
    void callBroadcast()
{
    // get broadcast.xml view
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View broadPop = li.inflate(R.layout.broadcast, null);
    contacts = (Button) broadPop.findViewById(R.id.contacts);


    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(broadPop);

    final EditText userInput = (EditText) broadPop.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

            result.setText(userInput.getText());
            }
          })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
          });

    // creating an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // showing
    alertDialog.show();

    contacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View contactList = li.inflate(R.layout.be_sponge_contacts, null);


            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter;
            ListView contact_list = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.contactList ); 
            String[] selectionArgs = null;
            String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
            String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP+"='"+("1")+"'";
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            final Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

            String[] from = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.rowTextViewChecked};

            listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Chats.this, R.layout.simplerow_checked, cur, from, to);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);


            alertDialogBuilder.setAdapter(listAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                }
            });

            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        selected = (CheckBox) contactList.findViewById(R.id.rowTextViewChecked);

                        if (selected.isChecked())
                        {
                            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            Toast.makeText(Chats.this, name+" was chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                  })

                .setNeutralButton("Select All", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        selected = (CheckBox) contactList.findViewById(R.id.rowTextViewChecked);

                        //setting all to be checked

                        selected.setChecked(true);

                        if (selected.isChecked())
                        {
                            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            Toast.makeText(Chats.this, name+" was chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            selected.setChecked(true);
                        }

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                  })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                  });

            // creating an alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // showing
            alertDialog.show();


        }
    });

    test = (TextView) broadPop.findViewById(R.id.namesChosen);

}
```

Comment: I have done research and still don't understand why the app crashes onClick by the if statement - because it is checking the CheckBox selected.isChecked()

Comment: even if (selected.isChecked()==true)    returns an error to the LogCat and still crashes

Comment: I have tried implementing and toggling the check boxes with multi choice AlertDialog- It is still not working... Please help